# How to retrieve all recursive children of parent row in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, rdbms

I've got a recursive query that's really stretching the limits of this Java monkey's SQL knowledge.  Now that it's finally 1:30 in the AM, it's probably time to start looking for some help.  This is one of the few times Google has failed me.

The table is as follows:

```
Parent_ID CHILD_ID QTY
25        26        1
25        27        2
26        28        1
26        29        1
26        30        2
27        31        1
27        32        1
27        33        2
```

I'm trying to get the following result, where the parent has every child listed below them.  Note that the qty's cascade as well.

```
BASE    PARENT_ID  CHILD_ID   QTY
25         25        26        1
25         25        27        2
25         26        28        1
25         26        29        1
25         26        30        1
25         27        31        2
25         27        32        2
25         27        33        4
26         26        28        1
26         26        29        1
26         26        30        2
27         27        31        1
27         27        32        1
27         27        33        2
```

I've tried several deviations of the following to no avail.

```
SELECT *
FROM MD_BOMS
START WITH PARENT_ID is not null
CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_ID = PARENT_ID
ORDER BY PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID
```

I'm using the Oracle database.  Any suggestions, ideas, etc. would be greatly appreciated.  This seems close, but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for: [Retrieve all Children and their Children, recursive SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299496/retreive-all-children-and-their-children-recursive-sql)

Based on ( [Retrieve all Children and their Children, recursive SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299496/retreive-all-children-and-their-children-recursive-sql?lq=1) )I've also tried the following but receive an "illegal reference ofa  query name in WITH clause" error:

```
with cte as (
    select  CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID as head
    from    MD_BOMS
    where   PARENT_ID is not null
    union all
    select  ch.CHILD_ID, ch.PARENT_ID, p.head
    from    MD_BOMS ch
    join    cte pa
    on      pa.CHILD_ID = ch.PARENT_ID
)
select  *
from    cte
```

Comment: I don't understand, how qty has to be calculated. Please explain.

Comment: Hi Olaf.  This particular structure models a Bill of Material (BOM).  It's a way of describing what components make up other components.  The short of it is that the component qtys are multiplicative.  For example, if there are 2 27s in a 25, then there would be 4 31s in a 25.  Looking back, I did make a typo in my original post.  There should only be 1 30 in a 25.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@AlexPoole answer is great, I just want to extend his answer with more intuitive variant of query for summing values along a path.
This variant based on  [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) feature, introduced in `Oracle 11g R2`.

```
with recursion_view(base, parent_id, child_id, qty) as (
   -- first step, get rows to start with
   select 
     parent_id base, 
     parent_id, 
     child_id, 
     qty
  from 
    md_boms

  union all

  -- subsequent steps
  select
    -- retain base value from previous level
    previous_level.base,
    -- get information from current level
    current_level.parent_id,
    current_level.child_id,
    -- accumulate sum 
    (previous_level.qty + current_level.qty) as qty 
  from
    recursion_view previous_level,
    md_boms        current_level
  where
    current_level.parent_id = previous_level.child_id

)
select 
  base, parent_id, child_id, qty
from 
  recursion_view
order by 
  base, parent_id, child_id
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36bfc/1) (extended with one data row to demonstrate work with more then 2 levels)

Comment: ThinkJet, this works great!  After I ugpraded from 10g to 11g R2, all I had to do was copy and paste and it worked like a charm.  The only thing I changed was putting multiply instead of addition, which gave me the correct qtys.  I was wholly surprised by both you and Alex's answers.  This helped me out quite a bit!

Comment: On more question if you can ... When I try to turn your query into a view, I receive a SQL Parse Exception:  Error(s) parsing SQL:
syntax error near *!* in the following:
with *!*recursion_view(base, parent_id, child_id, qty) as (
syntax error near *!* in the following:
with recursion_view*!*(base, parent_id, child_id, qty) as (

Comment: Depending on how I try to create the view, I receive Jun 28, 2013 12:42:41 PM oracle.dbtools.db.DBUtil handleException
SEVERE: Warning, unhandled exception: Closed Connection And another SEVERE: Warning, unhandled exception: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qkebCreateColInFro:1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Comment: @WillLovett - where are the `!` and `*` coming from in the error? You can turn it into a view by sticking `create view my_view as ` in front of it, and not changing anything else. If you're doing something else you might need to ask a new question showing the exact code you're using in the question.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've posted two screenshots: http://www.williverstravels.com/JDev/Forums/StackOverflow/17358109/ViewError.jpg and http://www.williverstravels.com/JDev/Forums/StackOverflow/17358109/InternalError.jpg The first one with the ! and * is when I am using JDeveloper 11g, using the Database Navigator, right-click on View and select "New View".  I receive the error when I click OK.  I can indeed create the view through a sql script, but when I attempt to view the data, I receive the ORA_00600 error.

Comment: @WillLovett - can't help you with JDeveloper. The ORA-600 looks like a bug, I can see two possibles. Works for me in 11.2.0.3 though. You said you upgraded to 11gR2; did you stop at 11.2.0.1 or patch up to the current patchset? Again, this is really a whole new question, and maybe one for [DBA.SE].

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks again Alex.  I downloaded straight from oracle website and installed.  My current version is 11.2.0.2.0.  Perhaps I need to patch somehow.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: After spending a good 6 hours on this, I decide not to use JDev's graphical editor, and simply write 

SELECT * FROM BOMS_VIEW;

And it works like a charm.  I just can't use data tab to view the records in the editor.  Wish I had known that 5 hours ago.

Answer (score 23):

You are close:

```
select connect_by_root parent_id base, parent_id, child_id, qty
from md_boms
connect by prior child_id = parent_id
order by base, parent_id, child_id;

          BASE  PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID        QTY
    ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
            25         25         26          1 
            25         25         27          2 
            25         26         28          1 
            25         26         29          1 
            25         26         30          2 
            25         27         31          1 
            25         27         32          1 
            25         27         33          2 
            26         26         28          1 
            26         26         29          1 
            26         26         30          2 
            27         27         31          1 
            27         27         32          1 
            27         27         33          2 

     14 rows selected
```

The [`connect_by_root` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/operators004.htm) gives you the base `parent_id`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2fc6/1).

I'm not sure how you're calculating your `qty`. I'm guessing you want the total for the path to the child, but that doesn't match what you've shown. As a starting point, then, borrowing *very* heavily from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8226980), you could try something like:

```
with hierarchy as (
  select connect_by_root parent_id base, parent_id, child_id, qty,
    sys_connect_by_path(child_id, '/') as path
  from md_boms
  connect by prior child_id = parent_id
)
select h.base, h.parent_id, h.child_id, sum(e.qty)
from hierarchy h
join hierarchy e on h.path like e.path ||'%'
group by h.base, h.parent_id, h.child_id
order by h.base, h.parent_id, h.child_id;

     BASE  PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID SUM(E.QTY)
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        25         25         26          1 
        25         25         27          2 
        25         26         28          2 
        25         26         29          2 
        25         26         30          3 
        25         27         31          3 
        25         27         32          3 
        25         27         33          4 
        26         26         28          1 
        26         26         29          1 
        26         26         30          2 
        27         27         31          1 
        27         27         32          1 
        27         27         33          2 

 14 rows selected
```

Comment: Alex, thank you!  While I went with ThinkJet's answer, this is everything I was looking for.  If I could upvote you I would.

Comment: Agree with @WillLovett :-)