# sql query oracle to fit a tree structure format

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

I have created these sample tables to create a json tree structure so that i can use jqtree to create a tree layout.

I want my json to be in the format

```
[
  {"id":1, "parentid": 0, "name": "Carnivores"},
  {"id":2, "parentid": 0, "name": "Herbivores"},
  {"id":3, "parentid": 1, "name": "Dogs"},
  {"id":4, "parentid": 3, "name": "Labradors"},  
  {"id":5, "parentid": 3, "name": "Pugs"},
  {"id":6, "parentid": 3, "name": "Terriers"}

]
```

The tables are as follows.

```
| catg_id       |   catg_name       | 
| —————-        |————————-          |
| 1             |   Carnivores      |
| 2             |   Herbivores      |



| animal_catg_id    | animal_catg_name      |   catg_id |
| —————-        |————————-                  |————————-  |
| 1             |   Dogs                    |   1       |
| 2             |   Cats                    |   1       |
| 3             |   Cows                    |   2       |
| 4             |   Buffalo                 |   2       |



| animal_id     | animal_name   | animal_catg_id    |
| —————-        |————————-      |   ————————-       |
| 1             |   labs        |   1               |
| 2             |   pugs        |   1               |
| 3             |   terriers    |   1               |
| 4             |   german      |   1               |
| 5             |   lion        |   2               |
| 6             |   tiger       |   2               |
```

I am assuming it would be hierarchical query, i have never written one before, i need some help with that. 
I don't know where to start and how to start it.

**EDIT**

One of the comments in the answers is that the schema design is not clear. 
What changes should I do to make to get the data in the json format, so that it maintains the hierarchy

**EDIT2**

My current query returns this table

```
Carnivores     |  Dogs    | labs
Carnivores     |  Dogs    | pugs
Carnivores     |  Dogs    | terriers
.......
```

Comment: `select id, parentid`  where is `parentid` in your tables??

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358109/how-to-retrieve-all-recursive-children-of-parent-row-in-oracle-sql) where it mentions the usage of Oracle's "connect by"

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I have deleted the query so that I don't confuse

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Should the schema design be changed for me to get the json format with hierarchical query? I really need to nail this down. I have been trying to work on this since 2 days.

Comment: @user525146, I just can not get the relationships between those tables. Can you for example forget about JSON and just do a select that will return you desired set?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri see my edit2 section
`select a.catg_name, b.animal_catg_name, d.animal_name inner join table2 b on table 3 d b.animal_catg_id = d.animal_ctg_id inner join table1 a on a.catg_id = b.catg_id` this is the query i wrote

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how people go into great lengths to describe their structure of tables instead of posting a few DDL statements along with some DML so that it would be reproducable.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you are proposing appears to have no correlation between the `ID`s you are assigning and the `ID`s in the tables this will make it difficult to connect anything from the client-side back to the database.

You would be better re-organising your tables so that you can put everything into a single hierarchical structure. Something like a Linnaean Taxonomy:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0050d/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Taxonomies ( ID, PARENT_ID, Category, Taxonomy, Common_Name ) AS
          SELECT  1, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER),  'Kingdom',     'Animalia',    'Animal'       FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  2,  1,    'Phylum',      'Chordata',    'Chordate'     FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  3,  2,    'Class',       'Mammalia',    'Mammal'       FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  4,  3,    'Order',       'Carnivora',   'Carnivore'    FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  5,  4,    'Family',      'Felidae',     'Feline'       FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  6,  5,    'Genus',       'Panthera',    'Tiger'         FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  7,  5,    'Genus',       'Felis',       'Cat'           FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  8,  5,    'Genus',       'Lynx',        'Lynx'          FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  9,  4,    'Family',      'Canidae',     'Canid'        FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 10,  9,    'Genus',       'Canis',       'Canine'       FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 10,    'Species',     'Canis Lupus', 'Gray Wolf'     FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 12, 11,    'Sub-Species', 'Canis Lupus Familiaris', 'Domestic Dog' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 13, 12,    'Breed',       NULL,          'Pug'           FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 14, 12,    'Breed',       NULL,          'German Shepherd' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 15, 12,    'Breed',       NULL,          'Labradors'     FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 16,  7,    'Species',     'Felis Catus', 'Domestic Cat'  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 17,  8,    'Species',     'Lynx Lynx',   'Eurasian Lynx' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 18,  8,    'Species',     'Lynx Rufus',  'Bobcat'        FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can extract the data relatively simply:

**Query 1 - Get everything taxonomically related to "Cat"**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM   Taxonomies
  START WITH Common_Name = 'Cat'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = ID
  ORDER BY LEVEL DESC
)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM   Taxonomies
  START WITH Common_Name = 'Cat'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY Common_Name
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0050d/1/0)**:

```
| ID | PARENT_ID | CATEGORY |    TAXONOMY |  COMMON_NAME |
|----|-----------|----------|-------------|--------------|
|  1 |    (null) |  Kingdom |    Animalia |       Animal |
|  2 |         1 |   Phylum |    Chordata |     Chordate |
|  3 |         2 |    Class |    Mammalia |       Mammal |
|  4 |         3 |    Order |   Carnivora |    Carnivore |
|  5 |         4 |   Family |     Felidae |       Feline |
|  7 |         5 |    Genus |       Felis |          Cat |
| 16 |         7 |  Species | Felis Catus | Domestic Cat |
```

**Query 2 - Get everything taxonomically related to "Canine"**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM   Taxonomies
  START WITH Common_Name = 'Canine'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = ID
  ORDER BY LEVEL DESC
)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM   Taxonomies
  START WITH Common_Name = 'Canine'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY Common_Name
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0050d/1/1)**:

```
| ID | PARENT_ID |    CATEGORY |               TAXONOMY |     COMMON_NAME |
|----|-----------|-------------|------------------------|-----------------|
|  1 |    (null) |     Kingdom |               Animalia |          Animal |
|  2 |         1 |      Phylum |               Chordata |        Chordate |
|  3 |         2 |       Class |               Mammalia |          Mammal |
|  4 |         3 |       Order |              Carnivora |       Carnivore |
|  9 |         4 |      Family |                Canidae |           Canid |
| 10 |         9 |       Genus |                  Canis |          Canine |
| 11 |        10 |     Species |            Canis Lupus |       Gray Wolf |
| 12 |        11 | Sub-Species | Canis Lupus Familiaris |    Domestic Dog |
| 13 |        12 |       Breed |                 (null) |             Pug |
| 14 |        12 |       Breed |                 (null) | German Shepherd |
| 15 |        12 |       Breed |                 (null) |       Labradors |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a hierarchical query from the Oracle documentation:

```
SELECT last_name, employee_id, manager_id, LEVEL
  FROM employees
  START WITH employee_id = 100
  CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY last_name;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Something like this in your case but your schema design isn't clear

```
 SELECT animal_name, level
  FROM animals
  START WITH parentid is null
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parentid;
```

Comment: Table 1 is the base table, which has root node, second table is next level and the 3rd table is the next set of children. Does it make sense ?